# how to truncate DisplayMember in C# ListBox?

Tags: c#, text, listbox, truncate

I have a winforms ListBox that displays a list of full file paths. But as you can see, the `Path` property is way too long. How can I get the ListBox to display only the filename and not the full path without adding an entirely new property to the list entries?

```
myListBox.DisplayMember = "Path";
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the filepaths to System.IO.FileInfo objects it should give you more options.

Try this:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\tmp");
List<System.IO.FileInfo> fiList = new List<System.IO.FileInfo>();
foreach(string f in files)
    fiList.Add(new System.IO.FileInfo(f));
myListBox.DataSource = fiList;
myListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
myListBox.ValueMember = "FullName";
```

Answer (score 1):

Without adding an entirely new property to the list entries you can use the DrawItem event of the list box (make sure to change the DrawMode property to OwnerDrawFixed).

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(lst[e.Index].DisplayValue), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
```